# HiClimR Hierarchical Climate Regionalization - Convert CRU data to run MultiVariate Clustering function and delimit to a specific region

Tags: r

I'm a newbie in R. I would like to use the HiClimR package to delimit areas with homogeneous climatic characteristics in Brazilian Semi-arid regions. I want to run the Multi-Variate Clustering model from CRU database with a 0.5 degrees spatial resolution time series (1901 - 2015), listing variables (cld, dtr, frs, pet, pre, tmn, tmp, tmx).

I don't understand how to convert the CRU database as an object to be read in the function HiClimR and how to delimit to a specific region.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a lot easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. Show the code you've already tried and describe exactly where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Multi-Variate Clustering

require(HiClimR)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Typical use of HiClimR for multi-variate clustering:                             #
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
 
## Load the test data included/loaded in the package (1 degree resolution)
x1 <- TestCase$x
lon <- TestCase$lon
lat <- TestCase$lat

Comment: How Ican convert CRU data base in same object like as in the example above ?? ## Load the test data included/loaded in the package (1 degree resolution)
x <- TestCase$x
lon <- TestCase$lon
lat <- TestCase$lat